# Getting record from second table row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table with the same field name and i want to display record from the two field columns.

```
Table_a
    id date          user    test
    1   2013-08-08   Adam    Various    
    2   2013-08-08   Paul    Record

    Table_b

      id date          user    test
        1   2013-08-08   Adam    Record    
        2   2013-08-08   Paul    Mytest


    $sql = "Select Table_a.date, Table_a.user, Table_a.test, Table_b.date, Table_b.user, Table_b.test FROM table_a, Table_b where Table_a.user like table_b AND table_a.Date = table_b.date AND table_b.Date = '".date("Y-m-d", strtotime("today"))."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 


 echo "<p'><b>" . $row['user'] . "</b></p>";
 echo "<p><b>". $row['test'] ."</b></p>";
 echo "<p><b>". $row['test'] ."</b></p>";
```

I want the result to be Adam -various -record for example.That is I want the third echo `"<p><b>". $row['test'] ."</b></p>";` to display record from table_b.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use SQL alias

```
SELECT column_name AS alias_name
```

Example from your code

```
$sql = "SELECT Table_a.date AS tableA_date, 
               Table_a.user AS tableA_user,
               Table_a.test AS tableA_test,
               Table_b.date AS tableB_date,
               Table_b.user AS tableB_user, 
               Table_b.test AS tableB_test
        FROM Table_a AS tableA,
             Table_b AS tableB
        WHERE tableA_user
        LIKE tableB 
        AND tableA_date = tableB_date
        AND tableD_date = '".date("Y-m-d", strtotime("today"))."'";
```

Comment: does strtotime() exists in mysql? I don't think it exists. I think it exists in php but not in mysql.

Comment: This query is being run in PHP and the string is concatenated so it will work just fine. There is probably a better way to grab the date but the question they are asking doesn't relate to getting the date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "Select
              a.date as adate,
              a.user as auser,
              a.test as atest,
              b.date as bdate,
              b.user as buser,
              b.test as btest
        FROM table_a a, Table_b b
        where 
              a.user like b.user
              AND a.Date = b.date
              AND b.Date = '".date("Y-m-d", strtotime("today"))."'";
echo "<p'><b>" . $row['auser'] . "</b></p>";
echo "<p><b>". $row['atest'] ."</b></p>";
echo "<p><b>". $row['btest'] ."</b></p>";
```

Note that I have written `a.user like b.user`. `a.user like b` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

user the below query

```
Select table_a.user,table_a.test,table_b.test FROM table_a left join table_b on
table_a.user=table_b.user where table_a.Date = table_b.date AND table_b.Date = curdate()
```

it will return result like below

[image]

think it will solve your problem.